# Querying the latest version of a row

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I have an database table set up as shown below:

```
copy_blocks
id (auto-increment int)
content (text)
parent_id (int)
```

When a piece of copy is inserted the first time, the parent_id is set to itself.  Example:

```
copy_blocks
id    content        parent_id
1     Hello, World   1
```

When that copy is updated by the user, new rows are inserted, but those row always points to the first version of the copy block.

```
copy_blocks
id    content         parent_id
2     Hello, World!   1
3     Heya, World!!   1
```

Structuring things this way allows me to either query a specific version of the content, or find the parent copy block and then look up the latest version.  (In this case, version #3)

So here's my question: Can anyone come up with a query that will always return the latest version of every content block?  Ideally the query would return the results below:

```
id    content         parent_id
3     Heya, World!!   1
```

I get the feeling it would have something to do with joining against itself.  I can't think of how to do it without at least two different queries or server-side code.

Comment: what rdbms are you using? and what have you tried?

Comment: I'm using MySQL, and right now I'm doing it server-side, which is unattractive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more option:

```
SELECT 
      c.*
FROM 
        ( SELECT parent_id
               , MAX(id) AS id
          FROM copy_blocks
          GROUP BY parent_id
        ) AS dc
    JOIN
        copy_blocks AS c
      ON 
        (c.parent_id, c.id) = (dc.parent_id, dc.id)
```

Comment: From what I read, JOIN is more efficient than IN(), so I think I like your answer better.  In a small test, your query ran in  0.0359 sec while Pablo's ran in 0.0365.  That's a pretty small difference, but then again, the table only has 3 test rows in it.  Overall, I vote your answer the winner!  Thanks to Pablo, however, for your version as well.

Comment: @Anthony: is your table using InnoDB or MyISAM storage engine?

Comment: Currently I'm setting things to MyISAM.  From what I've read, MyISAM is better at reading quickly and InnoDB is better at writing quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select id, content, parent_id
  from copy_blocks
 where (id, parent_id) in (
     select max(id), parent_id from copy_blocks group by parent_id
 )
```

If your table is too big, query might get slow. Try to add some indices to improve it if that's the case.

Comment: This works well!  I've added an index on parent_id and id, so hopefully that will keep things reasonable.  Thanks Pablo!